# Build Error (IOS) after installing expo in a bare React Native Project

Tags: ios, reactjs, swift, react-native

I created a React Native Project using React Native CLI then installed expo as mentioned in the documentation [here](https://docs.expo.dev/bare/installing-expo-modules/)

I used the Automatic Method and ran `npx install-expo-modules@latest`
After that I ran `npx pod-install` then `npx react-native run-ios`

But I am getting the following error after that,

[image]

I have the following dependencies,

```
"expo": "^47.0.0",
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-native": "0.71.1",
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I just needed to add a distribution certificate to the MacOS key chain, this person's issue on GitHub gives you a good idea on how to do it: https://github.com/expo/eas-cli/issues/1331. I highly recommend viewing the post by [KiwiKilian](https://github.com/KiwiKilian). You can access it [here](https://github.com/expo/eas-cli/issues/1331#issuecomment-1235603312)

After adding the certificate to the keychain, the error just went away for me.

#### Useful resources

- https://support.apple.com/en-au/guide/keychain-access/kyca1083/mac
- https://support.magplus.com/hc/en-us/articles/203808748-iOS-Creating-a-Distribution-Certificate-and-p12-File
- https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/662300
- https://developer.apple.com/support/expiration/

Hope it helped!!